# Are there any big size open source robot project(servant like robot maybe)

Tags: mobile-robot

I am trying to build a big size robot (150CM height) like this:

[image]

But I don't have mechanical engineering knowledge for that. Also it's only a prototype to show how the robot will act(it's more relies on image/voice recognizing and processing). So I am looking for an open source project to build a robot that it's easy and cheap to build.(I mean something like instructable projects)

Answer (score 1):

I think that your best bet is to start with an [InMoov](http://inmoov.fr/build-yours/) and to customize it to add a mobile base.

InMoov is a 3D-printed, open source, life size robot created by Gael Langevin. It's pretty amazing.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I would look at the Flash Robotics "Flash", http://flashrobotics.com/products/flash

If you follow the "documentation" link you will find complete documentation for the robot. Yes, it is open-source, and you can build the entire robot from their plans and BOM. There are YouTube videos if you search "emys flash robot."

Emys is the head alone. There is a pro model and a kids model. I much prefer the pro model. The entire robot including the head is called "Flash" or "Flash Robot."

I intend to build a version of the Emys head for a project I'm working on. The body would have been perfect at one time, but now I'm living in a motorhome which doesn't have enough room. :(